# Message " 'echo.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." when starting shell

Tags: eclipse, perl, shell, echo

When starting my shell, I get a message :" 'echo.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." I am not sure where it comes from. The problem is, that when I run my perl scripts as external tools in eclipse, this message is also printed in the eclipse console after the output of the scripts. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the **.** at the end of **echo.** command used in the perl script.

To locate the perl script involved in a directory and all sub directories, use:

```
grep -irH "echo[.]" .
```

This other command-line below automatically update **all** perl script**s** found in current directory and sub directories; it replaces any **echo.** encountered with **echo**

**WARNING**: backup the directory before running the command-line below:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I xxxx sed -i 's/echo[.]/echo/g' xxxx
```

Comment: I don't get this: is this on Windows or Linux? I've assumed this was Windows because the "... is not recognized" is a typical Windows CMD message. But then, `echo.` is perfectly valid in Windows CMD, so why was there a problem with it? On the other hand, @Jayjargot's solution is a Linux command-line. And @Olena confirmed this worked. Please explain, someone...

Comment: @sferencik I did not even notice this error message was a Windows one. Offcourse my answer is for *NUX.

Comment: @sferencik The solution is working with **cygwin** on Windows (probably). And it will work as well on Windows 10 by the end of the year...

Comment: I had this problem on Windows. I did not use the command line command given by the Jay jargot, but I found the echo. line in my .cmd files (I had only four files) and changed it. And it worked pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. So the only thing left which I don't understand is what's wrong with `echo.`, which is a perfectly valid command in Windows CMD...

Answer (score 2):

Barbara Jensen provided the best answer in a comment (quoted below)

Echo. in Windows CMD should print a blank line, but in some situations, it returns the "is not recognized as an internal or external command..." error. I suspect it's cmdextensions or similar.

Barbara says "echo/" replaces it and this worked perfectly for me. Thanks B.

> echo. is supposed to display a blank line; it is not invalid Windows command. I have used this in batch files for at least 15y and it went bad for me very recently. Interestingly for me, its working sometimes (the windows that I've set up for compiling) and not others (fresh ones). If I change the echo. to echo/ in my batch files, they work again. – Barbara Jensen Feb 14 at 13:55

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the top search hit when searching for the error message: one can also end up with this intermittent error message when the current directory contains a file named `echo`, even if it's empty. It's easy to diagnose this possibility: move to another directory and check if `echo.` works. It should normally print an empty line in cmd, where `echo` is [a built-in command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo). If `echo.` works in other directories: rename or remove the file called `echo`.

Answer (score -2):

Figure out which one of your shell startup files contains the misspelling and remove it (the misspelling, not the file).

Comment: What is the misspelling?

Comment: `echo.` Note the dot at the end.

Comment: echo. is supposed to display a blank line; it is not invalid Windows command.  I have used this in batch files for at least 15y and it went bad for me very recently.  Interestingly for me, its working sometimes (the windows that I've set up for compiling) and not others (fresh ones).  If I change the echo. to echo/ in my batch files, they work again.